# Allow multiple voting

Tags: feature-request, answers, voting

The goal is to have the best answer on top, not penalize good answers and not have complicated the rep balance.

### The scenario

There are some really good questions which ask exactly what you want to know so you up vote the question without significantly affecting its three digit score. You eagerly scroll down to the first of three answers (I am simplifying here) which is almost as old as the question. It is very good. It cites three sources, has a great summary in the first paragraph, and enough detail to fully understand the answer and it's implications. It could be a poster child for a good answer. It fully deserves its four digit score.

You scroll to the second answer. It is a year younger reflects both the changes in the technology and simplifies things making understanding easier. It is a better answer than the first, but since it is newer it only has a three digit score.

You scroll to the third answer. This guy has three short sentences that explain every thing in a head slapping fashion. Of course, it is so simple. This is the best answer, and there are folks that agree because in the thirty minutes it already has a two digit score!

### The conundrum

All three answers deserve an upvote, but that won't put the best answer on top.

### The proposal

On questions with multiple answers with two digit scores and a difference of score of no less than 15 allow users that have already voted adjacent answers up to cast a second upvote to the lower ranked question with a tool hint this answer is better than the one above. I am not recommending any cost for this vote and if rep is awarded for this second vote it should be less than a first vote, and should be stored as a relative vote (keep track of which answer(s) it was better than). We probably want to impose a minimum user rep to cast as well (the casting of downvotes should be old hat before being allowed to do this).

### Related ideas

If this proposal is implemented It would be cool to add badges for receiving such votes on your answers. Perhaps bronze for one, silver four at least twenty votes across five such answers, and gold for thirty votes each on ten answers.

Comment: Too complicated in my opinion. I'm not against the core idea, but would prefer more simple way. What I have in mind is making a bounty affect answers order when sorted by votes, e.g. 50 points bounty will be counted as 5 upvotes. This way you can place a bounty on such "lower scored answer" to bump it upwards. All the required infrastructure already exists and it's only matter of tweaking the sort algorithm. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That could be interesting, although I worry a bit about putting all that power into a single random person's hands. "Good content floats to the top" is such a core principle, that I'd hate to see people legitimately game (like by floating their friends answers). It'd be interesting to look into allowing the asker some capabilities like that, though. They can already choose which answer is at the top by accepting it, but I wonder if we could bring that any further. I'm not completely sure what that would look like, or how often it would actually happen.

Answer (score 2):

I definitely like your premise, but I'm not completely convinced that multiple votes is the best way to go about fixing it. Situations like this are all too common, especially on a site like Stack Overflow which not only documents the ever-changing landscape of development tools, but has also been around for longer than other sites in the network. Finding a way to prioritize more relevant content--or in my eyes, even just remind readers to look down a few answers for it--would be fantastic.

However, part of the effectiveness, and even the fun, of Stack Exchange comes in its simplicity. Adding complex rules about who is allowed to vote a second time and on what makes it harder to follow, and even beyond that, just makes it take more work to use and maintain. I know that each person gets one vote, and as a result, I know each post is voted on fairly and without too much bias.

Beyond the simplicity aspects, I worry that this would open the system to gaming. People already try to cheat the system by creating sockpuppet accounts and trying to vote multiple times on single posts, imagine what will happen when we encourage it. It will bring us just that much closer to being a popularity contest.

Last but not least, re: making this a privilege, I'd worry what that would say about low-rep users in the network. I like, and I know a lot of other people do too, that as it stands, a 500,000-rep user has the same voting capabilities as a 125-rep one. It keeps things very fair. Ideally, I figure, everyone could vote. Unfortunately, we need a bit of a limit in there just to make sockpuppets more difficult, and to make sure voters actually know what they're doing. But I don't think we need anything put in place to make voting more skewed towards higher-rep users. That'll just irritate users, and compromise the system's integrity.

Again, I think the problem you've described is a very real one, but I'm not sure multiple votes is the right solution. That all said, I really don't know what is.

Comment: In response to the minimum rep, I think it should be low, definitely less than the 100 association bonus, but more than downvote

Comment: @hildred I think it's more a matter of principle. You could say "anyone with 17 rep can double-vote," but that's still telling users that one person's votes matter more than someone else's. Although if it's less than 101, it might as well just be for everyone. I don't see a benefit in limiting it past just "Vote Up" if everyone with an association bonus has access to it.